# Looking for a guitar name

Tags: electric-guitar

My grandpa is looking for the name of a guitar he used to play with when he was younger. He tells me that the electric guitar brand is something like "Andrea", "Andrezza" or "Andre", he also tells me that the manufacture is Italian. Does anybody have any idea of the manufacture of this guitar? Or can you find this guitar anywhere online?

The electric guitar's body is white, the pick guard has golden dots and the neck is black.

[image: Picture of guitar to be identified]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Avanti, Anastasio Fasanaro, Andrea Tacchi, Adona, Anea, Angella, Antonio de Torres? Here are guitar companies by letter and logo.
https://www.guitar-list.com/logos

Comment: This clearly isn't any of present major manufacturers. If you want to identify it, provide more details. E.g. the sticker you added indeed suggests it is Italian. What is on the front of the headstock? Is there anything on the back of the headstock? Are there any writings, names, labels on any other parts of the instrument?

Comment: I don't have any more names on the headstock., I do have a name in a metal piece in the front of the guitar, is something like: "Davoli", I'll add a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your last pictures, it seems that it is a "wandre davoli".

[Here](https://www.vintageandrare.com/product/Wandre-Twist-Davoli-Amp-1960-Sparkle-Red-46082) you can find a picture, with the brand and some info. The colour is not the exact same but every thing else is: form of the pickup guard, electronics and especially that very peculiar shape on the pickups.

You can also have a look [here](https://jacquespedals.com/wandre-guitars/), look for the red one!

Answer (score 3):

Googling "Davoli pickups" yields this forum thread: https://www.thegearpage.net/board/index.php?threads/anyone-know-what-davoli-pickups-are.2153806/
in which someone wrote "they're the Italian-made pickups found in Wandre guitars". This seems like a name that matches your description.

There is some more information in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wandre_Guitars

Comment: Was that simultaneous?

Comment: @Tom It looks like your answer came 13 seconds earlier (when I hover over the date).

Comment: @Tom yes, I was typing, saw Tom posted, so I hit "send" as well. That's SE, what to do?